# proving $Span(S)$ is the intersection of all subspaces $W$ of $V$ containing $S$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

**My attempt**

lemma: $S\subset W$ iff $Span(S)\subset W$

$$Span(S)=\bigcap^{\infty}_{i=1}\{W_i |S\subset W_i\subset V\}$$

Let $v\in Span(S)$, then by lemma it's in $W_i$ for all $i$, so $v\in\bigcap^{\infty}_{i=1}\{W_i |S\subset W_i\subset V\}$, we have $Span(S)\subseteq\bigcap^{\infty}_{i=1}\{W_i |S\subset W_i\subset V\}$.

Let $v\in \bigcap^{\infty}_{i=1}\{W_i |S\subset W_i\subset V\},\color{red}{\text{then $v\in S$ by the set property}}$, then $v\in Span(S)$ by lemma, so $\bigcap^{\infty}_{i=1}\{W_i |S\subset W_i\subset V\}\subseteq Span(S)$

**I am not sure if the red claim is legitimate**

Thank you for any comments

---

I just realised I abused the set notation.

Comment: The red claim seems false,, as $v\in{\rm span} \, S$ does not mean $v\in S.$ For example $S=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ and its span is equal $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I agree with your comments. But what I'm trying to say here is $S\subset W_i$ for all $i$, and $v\in \bigcap^{\infty}_{i=1} W_i$, so $v\in S$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$. Let $\text{Span(S)}=\{\sum_n k_is_i, k_i \in K, s_i \in S, n < + \infty \}$. Let $W$ be the intersection of all subspaces of $V$ containing $S$. Then $\text{Span}(S) \subset W$ of course. You can also check that $W \subset \text{Span}(S)$ by verifying that $\text{Span}(S)$ satisfies the subspace axioms and contains $S$.